# Зачем писать const в конструкторе

Tags: c++, массивы, ооп, конструктор, константа

```
class World
{
public:
    World(const char* str);

private:
    char* string[255];
}
```

или

```
class World
{
public:
    World(char* str) const;

private:
    char* string[255];
}
```

И в чём отличие первого варианта от второго?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, так

```
World(char* str) const;
```

вы не напишете. А так -

```
World(char* str);
```

запросто, только вот при этом вы не сможете написать, например,

```
World w("Hello");
```

потому что строковый литерал приводится только к `const char*`, но не к `char*`.

Написать `char*` - по сути значит предупредить компилятор, что вы собираетесь менять эту строку.

Comment: Спасибо. А в get/set почему так пишут например: void setStr(char* str) const; Почему не void setStr(const char* str)

Comment: Вы никак не сообразите, что эти `const` никак не связаны друг с другом! Первый - относится к объекту класса, т.е., например, у вас `const World w("Hello");` - теперь вы сможете вызвать для `w` только те методы, после которых стоит `const`. А ёconst` внутри скобок относится к аргументу.

Comment: Всё понял, спасибки